# How can I disable user actions when load mask is shown

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am using ExtJS 4. My requirement is that when I show a load mask, user clicks should be ignored. How can I achieve this?

Comment: That's kinda what the load mask does.. can you elaborate on your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the loadmask on document body as follows...

// show a spinner during all Ajax requests
    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {
        msg: "Please wait..."
    });

```
// Ajax loading message..
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', myMask.show, myMask);
Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', myMask.hide, myMask);
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', myMask.hide, myMask);
```

So When you have a process on your application (Generally In Extjs4 all the major processes performed by Ajax call) than you can get a mask on entire body.

Or if it's not your requirement than you can use following method as well...

setLoading( Boolean/Object/String load, Boolean targetEl ) : Ext.LoadMask
This method allows you to show or hide a LoadMask on top of this component.

Parameters
load : Boolean/Object/String
True to show the default LoadMask, a config object that will be passed to the LoadMask constructor, or a message String to show. False to hide the current LoadMask.
targetEl : Boolean
True to mask the targetEl of this Component instead of the this.el. For example, setting this to true on a Panel will cause only the body to be masked. (defaults to false)
Returns
Ext.LoadMask
The LoadMask instance that has just been shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the loadMask is loading by using element.loadMask.loading property

```
xtype: 'button',
handler: function() {
    this.setLoading(true);
    if (!this.loadMask.loading) {
        //click action
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Let me elaborate on my requirement. I am masking the entire viewport, when a certain action is in progress.During this time, if the user clicks any where on the screen, they should be ignored. there are lot of tabs and other elements on my page and the user click on all of them should not be queued.Based on your suggestion I have to go to each element to accomplish this. I was looking for a centralised manner of disabling user clicks when viewport mask is shown

Comment: Using setLoading(true) on the viewport masks the whole screen and elements inside the viewport should not be clickable. Atleast they're not when I test. Ext.getCmp('viewport').setLoading(true);